# How to gradually increase and decrease the speed of a motor using IR remote

Tags: motor

I am making an IR controlled helicopter and I have the very basic part of the code done, but I don't know how to make the motor gradually increase speed. I want the motor to gradually increase speed when you hold the button on the IR remote and hold its speed when you stop pushing the button. And the same for when the helicopter goes down.
Here is the code:

```
   #include <IRremote.h>
   #include <Servo.h>
   #define enA 9
   #define enB 11
   #define in1 6
   #define in2 7
   #define in3 4
   #define in4 5

   Servo ball1;

   int IR_RECEIVE_PIN = 2;
   IRrecv IrReceiver(IR_RECEIVE_PIN);
   decode_results results;

   void setup() {
     Serial.begin(9600);
     IrReceiver.enableIRIn();

     ball1.attach(10);

     pinMode(in1, OUTPUT);
     pinMode(in2, OUTPUT);
     pinMode(in3, OUTPUT);
     pinMode(in4, OUTPUT);
   }
   void loop() {
     if (IrReceiver.decode(&results)) {
       switch (results.value) {

         case 0xFFA857:
           Serial.println("case: UP");
           digitalWrite(enA, 255);
           digitalWrite(in1, HIGH);
           digitalWrite(in2, LOW);
           break;

         case 0xFFE01F:
           Serial.println("case: DOWN");
           digitalWrite(enA, 120);
           digitalWrite(in1, LOW);
           digitalWrite(in2, LOW);
           break;

         case 0xFF18E7:
           Serial.println("case: FORWARD");
           ball1.write(90);
           break;

         case 0xFF10EF:
           Serial.println("case: LEFT");
           digitalWrite(in3, LOW);
           digitalWrite(in4, LOW);
           break;

         case 0xFF5AA5:
           Serial.println("case: RIGHT");
           digitalWrite(in3, HIGH);
           digitalWrite(in4, LOW);
           break;

         case 0xFF48B5:
           Serial.println("case: BACKWARD");
           ball1.write( ? ); // I need help on the direction of the linear servo
           break;
       }

       Serial.println(results.value, HEX);
       IrReceiver.resume();
     }
   }
```

It is the same code I used to control a RGB LED (But modified). Would it be possible to upload this code to an IC? I already programmed my UNO as an ISP, but there seems to be a problem. Also, I am using a linear servo for the pitch of the helicopter, can someone please show me how to change the direction of a linear servo? I have one that is similar to the Pico linear servo.

Comment: Should each `case` statement have a matching `break` statement?

Comment: Yes, I removed them when I was trying something, but I added them back now... Thanks!

Comment: Properly indenting your code would make it much easier to follow.

Comment: Okay, I indented it...

Comment: Every time you receive an "up" code increase the speed. Every time you receive a "down" code decrease the speed. IR doesn't (usually) have a concept of "press" and "release", only "press" and it sends the code repeatedly while it's pressed.

Comment: Mhh, normally you don't see IR controlled flight models, because it is too unreliable and it won't work in direct sunlight (because the IR light from the sun already saturates the sensor, so that it cannot see the signal from the sender). Are you sure, that you want to use IR? A good RF sender and receiver (like in other flight models) are nornally way better

Comment: Hi chrisl, thank you! I will see if I can get an RF sender and receiver... I used IR because it is all I have now, but I will look into your idea. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could separate reading the controls and taking actions and there are several ways of doing that, one example shown below where the switch() can be used to read all commands and according to the value call one or more atomic functions. For instance, one function to change speed and another one to change direction, and perhaps calling several functions in a row for more complex tasks like take off and land (I have no idea how those helicopter projects works).

On each case you do the validation, min and max allowed values, dependencies on other factors and alike.

```
void loop() {

  if (IrReceiver.decode(&results)) {

    switch (results.value) {

      case 0xFFA857: // up
        verticalSpeed = verticalSpeed + verticalSpeedStep;
        if (verticalSpeed > maxVerticalSpeed) verticalSpeed = maxVerticalSpeed;
        setVericalMotor();
        break;

      case 0xFFE01F: //down
        verticalSpeed = verticalSpeed - verticalSpeedStep;
        if (verticalSpeed < 0) verticalSpeed = 0;
        setVericalMotor();
        break;

    }
  }
}

void setVericalMotor() {
  digitalWrite(in1, HIGH);
  digitalWrite(in2, LOW);
  digitalWrite(enA, verticalSpeed);
}
```

As for your question regarding the servo, they usually run from 0 to 180 degrees, so tey anything in that range as the "reverse" for 90 degrees for Forward (normally that should be 0 or 180).

Comment: Thank you for the help!!

Comment: I have not worked with verticalSpeed before, and the compiler says it is not declared in a scope along with verticalSpeedStep, and maxVerticalSpeed... Could you please help me?

Comment: The code I showed you is not a complete program, just an idea how to design your program and as part of it you have to declare the variables.  As you are new to programming I suggest you follow one of the many getting started with Arduino tutorials you can find on arduino.cc and many other websites.

Comment: Okay, thank you!